# Getting error in Invoke-expression Call

Tags: powershell

My requirement is to register dlls in GAC, and i am using gacutil for the same.The coe i have written is as follows.

```
function RegisterAssembliesToGAC([string]$frameworkPath,[string]$GACDllLocation)
{
    try
    {
       $Dirs = Get-ChildItem $GACDllLocation -Recurse 
        $Dlls = $Dirs | Where { $_.extension -eq ".dll" }

        ForEach($dll in $Dlls)
        { 

            C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\gacutil.exe -i $dll.FullName
        }   

    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
    write-host $_.Exception.Message `n;
    }

}
```

This works fine for me.Now I as shown $frameworkpath is an argument and i want to pass its value as parameter.So i modified my code as follows

```
function RegisterAssembliesToGAC([string]$frameworkPath,[string]$GACDllLocation)
{
    try
    {
       $Dirs = Get-ChildItem $GACDllLocation -Recurse 
        $Dlls = $Dirs | Where { $_.extension -eq ".dll" }

        ForEach($dll in $Dlls)
        {       

        $frameworkPath="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"  
    $gacpath=[string]$frameworkPath + "\gacutil.exe"
        Invoke-Expression "$gacpath -i $dll.FullName"


        }   

    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
    write-host $_.Exception.Message `n;
    }

}
```

This Gives an error as: Failure adding assembly to the cache:   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.Tried alot,Could not fix it.
Please Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

`$frameworkPath` parameter have no sense if in the script you always give it a value:

`$frameworkPath="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"`

Second: you need to make this change:

```
Invoke-Expression "$gacpath -i $($dll.FullName)"
```

because in a string the variable parameter expansion need to be enclosed in a `$()`.
If in the script  you add before the `iex` this `"$gacpath -i $dll.FullName"` you can see how is evaluated.

Third: I suggest to use join-path cmdlet to build you path:

```
$gacpath= join-path $frameworkPath "gacutil.exe"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked.And that $frameworkpath,i have assigned in function just to show what path i am forming.Anyways thanks alot.